# Adding AND OR structure in MDX query

Tags: mdx

I would like to have a condition like this in an MDX query with nested ANDs and ORs -

```
{[Ele1].[Value].&[1000] AND ([Ele2].[Value].&[20] OR
[Ele3].[Value].&[200]) AND [Ele4].[Value].&[15] AND
([Ele5].[Value].&[10] OR [Ele6].[Value].&[100])}
```

where all the elements are in different hierarchies.

I would like to know if it is possible to implement this and where I can put it in the query if it is possible. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this a predicate? Which clause of the `MDX` script will it be placed?

Comment: I dont have a solution . Tried putting it in the where clause and as a subselect . It did not work. Need to use all these conditions in the same clause but I am not sure which clause I should put it in.

Comment: I just don't understand the question - you mention `condition` but this is just a member `[Ele1].[Value].&[1000]` ...it does not evaluate to true or false so how can it be a condition?

Comment: I actually wanted to filter the value of Ele1. I want to have the records where the value is 1000 for Ele1. I would want to filter many such elements likewise.

Answer (score 0):

In mdx:

A `Set` is the logical equivalent of `AND`

Nested `EXISTS` can represent an `OR`

---

To filter members of a set you can use the function `FILTER`:

```
FILTER (
   [Ele1].[Value].[Value].MEMBERS AS S
  ,S.CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE = 1000
)
```

BUT the above is exactly the same as:

```
{[Ele1].[Value].&[1000]}
```